# React.js en dos paginas

Tags: reactjs

verán soy muy nuevo en esto, creo que peor que un noob...

quiero saber como poner react en dos paginas, como por ejemplo...
tengo mi pagina principal (en react por supuesto) y le doy clic a un enlace.
1... ¿como hago una nueva pagina dentro de mi proyecto? (lo sé puede sonar muy noob).
2... ¿como hacer esa nueva pagina que tambien contenga react? 
3... ¿saben como poner three.js en esa nueva pagina? (algo asi como un cubo o algo de ejemplo).

muchas gracias a los que me escuchen.
soy demasiado noob (gato llorando) :,'c

Comment: Cordial saludo compañero puedes mostrarnos que has hecho hasta el momento, así podremos ayudarte mas fácil, saludos

Comment: Hola Sunex, bienvenido a SOes. Por favor, pásate por [¿Cómo elaboro una bueba pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ahí encontrarás los consejos necesarios para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea compatible con las pautas de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Te aporto un ejemplo.

```
<BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>                           
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home2} />
                <Route exact path="/inicio" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/salud" component={Salud} /> 
                <Route exact path="/bip" component={Bip} />       
                <Route component={NotFound} />                                      
              </Switch>   
</BrowserRouter>
```

Te recomiendo documentarte un poco en cuanto a react-router-dom antes de utilizarlo ya que hay cosas que debes dominar antes de aplicar, por ejemplo, el "exact path" significa que si la ruta a la cual es redirigida es EXACTAMENTE IGUAL se va a redirigir a esa ruta.. pero, si no la tiene, te va redirigir a la más cercana. En el caso del not found es cuando no coincide ninguna de esas rutas, espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: muchas gracias ya me he documentado mejor y pude lograr implementar three.js aun me falta lo de los links pero hasta donde he leido es como me explicaste con react-router-dom
Muchas Gracias <3